# How to call a child of CreateView multiple times within another view

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to write a view that receives an Excel file from an HTML form and then inserts the values into the database. I am already having a CreateView and I want to call it multiple times to insert the Excel file contents into the database.

Here is my code:

```py
class AView(TemplateView):
    template_name = '/path/to/template/upload.html'

    def post(self, request):
        file = request.FILES['file']
        wb = load_workbook(file)
        for ws in wb.worksheets:
            for value_1, value_2 in zip(worksheet['A'], worksheet['B']):
                value_1 = value_1.value
                value_2 = value_2.value
```

The part of reading the excel file is correct, and I am not asking about it. My question is how to call my CreateView multiple times for each iteration. Is it possible?

---

Edit #1:

Here is the implementation of my CreateView, it is a child of the `CreateView` generic view.

```py
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['value_1', 'value_2']
```

Comment: Can you show the `CreateView` and the function want to call on the `CreateView`?

Comment: @DeanElliott I just did.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `CreateView` as many times as you want. You just need to make sure you have the correct arguments for it. I'm not sure what your `CreateView` looks like but this is how you would call it.

```
from somewhere.views import YourCreateView


class AView(TemplateView):
    template_name = '/path/to/template/upload.html'

    def post(self, request):
        file = request.FILES['file']
        wb = load_workbook(file)

        view = YourCreateView()
        for ws in wb.worksheets:
            for value_1, value_2 in zip(worksheet['A'], worksheet['B']):
                value_1 = value_1.value
                value_2 = value_2.value

                view.some_method()  # method on the view, could be .save()
```

Comment: How to pass the values?

Comment: The same way you would call any function, if your `CreateView` has a function called `do_something(param1, param2)` with these two params, you would call it like `view.do_something(someValue1, someValue2)`.